# Python: Mongodb: script in python not able to query & print all the records from mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

I have records i.e student_name, student_grade in mongodb

After inserting records i am trying to print all the records.

```
student_name,student_grade = raw_input("enter studentname & grade:").split(',')
    #place value
            student_record = {'name':student_name,'grade':student_grade}
    #insert record
            db.collection.insert_one(student_record)
            count+=1
    #find all record
                    for record in db.collection.find_one():
                            print(record[1]+','+record[2])
```

Here i am getting after running my script as output:

```
do you want to insert a record?y
enter studentname & grade:sam,A
r,a
i,d
a,m
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need

```
#find all records
for record in db.collection.find():
print(record['name']+','+record['grade'])
```

Indentations in your example are also not correct, I hope they are correct in your real code